# Fetch mail from MSN/Windows Live! in Evolution

Tags: email, evolution

I'm trying to sync a Hotmail/Windows Live/MSN email account to Evolution - however I'm unable to do so with both POP and IMAP. If I understand correctly this is because Microsoft blocks all email clients other than Outlook. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of hunting through old threads on the forums. I was mistaken that POP is disabled for all non-Microsoft clients. Here are the settings that worked for me.

In Evolution go to Edit -> Preferences. Choose your MSN/Live email account and select "Edit".

## Receiving Settings

- **Server Type**: POP
- **Server**: pop3.live.com:995
- **Username**: *Windows Live Email Address*
- **Use SSL Connection**: SSL encryption
- **Authentication Type**: Password

## Sending Settings

- **Server Type**: SMTP
- **Server**: smtp.live.com:587
- **Use Secure Connection**: TLS Encryption
- **Server Requires Authentication**
- **Authentication**: Plain
- **Username**: *Windows Live Email Address*

As a side note. When you try to send mail for the first time it will fail. You will get an email from Windows with a link to confirm you are a person and enable this functionality. After that you can Send as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail does indeed support POP3:

> http://news.softpedia.com/news/Windows-Live-Hotmail-POP3-Support-Now-Worldwide-106772.shtml

The details for connecting are also included in the article.